# PGAdmin 4 won't launch, giving error "The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted"

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, pgadmin-4

I'm getting an error on launching PGadmin4 right after installing "postgresql-12.14-1-windows-x64" on Windows Server 2012R2 Build 9600.

I've tried installing PostgreSQL without pgadmin and installing it separatly after, tried diffrent versions of pgadmin4 non of that seems to help, i'm always getting the same error.

Tried deleting everything from AppData folder of Pgadmin both Local and Roaming, but no result.

Also tried intalling on a diffrent machine with excact same OS - there was a succes on launching PGAdmin.

The PostgreSQL server is running, i can telnet its port from other machine in local network.

**Guessing, there is something about the line "File "ssl.py"", because every path before it was full.**

Ofc running everything as administrator.

Been punching with this problem for a few days, hoping to get some help with it! Full output, that i'm getting in PGadmin window:

"The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:

```
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe -s C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment:
  - ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
  - APPDATA: C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming
  - CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \\.\pipe\crashpad_1428_KWJZEMYPAOXYAGDS
  - CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Произошел сбой NW.js. Перезапустить?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
  - CLIENTNAME: DDADMIN
  - CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
  - CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - COMPUTERNAME: EPS
  - ComSpec: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
  - FP_NO_HOST_CHECK: NO
  - HOMEDRIVE: C:
  - HOMEPATH: \Users\<USERNAME>
  - LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local
  - LOGONSERVER: \\DC1
  - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 4
  - OS: Windows_NT
  - Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
  - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: bacd94c2-cabf-4152-9e40-a3fce8054470
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 61917
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
  - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
  - PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
  - PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
  - PROCESSOR_REVISION: 9e09
  - ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
  - ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
  - ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
  - ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
  - PSModulePath: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
  - PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
  - SESSIONNAME: RDP-Tcp#7
  - SystemDrive: C:
  - SystemRoot: C:\Windows
  - TEMP: C:\Users\0061~1.DOB\AppData\Local\Temp\2
  - TMP: C:\Users\0061~1.DOB\AppData\Local\Temp\2
  - USERDNSDOMAIN: <DOMAIN NAME>.LOCAL
  - USERDOMAIN: <DOMAIN NAME>
  - USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: <DOMAIN NAME>
  - USERNAME: <USERNAME>
  - USERPROFILE: C:\Users\<USERNAME>
  - windir: C:\Windows
--------------------------------------------------------

Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.014 Sec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 38, in <module>
import config
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import socketio
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\socketio\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\socketio\client.py", line 7, in <module>
    import engineio
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\engineio\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\engineio\client.py", line 6, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "ssl.py", line 99, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: �� ������ ��������� ������."
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this as well and corrected by taking two steps. First I installed Python (not sure if this impacts but a lot of the other stack issues say 'missing python stuff')

I then downloaded the pgAdmin installer directly and installed that. Even though one 'came' with the postgres install this worked and opening that (as administrator) seemed to correct the issue.

Link used was https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/

Comment: The pgAdmin installed with PostgreSQL did not work for me too, but installing it separately solved the issue.